# Finding the solution to $x^2y''+xy'-y=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The original question I encountered merely asks to verify that $y=\lambda x-\mu /x$ is a solution of the ODE: $x^2y''+xy'-y=0$. This is a trivial task. I am wondering how can one work in reverse and try to "guess" the format of the general solution. It would be great if anyone could share analytic methods to "solve" this ODE. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "work in reverse"? That is the general solution already.

Comment: @JackLeGrüß Thanks for sharing. That serves my purpose. Cheers :)

Comment: This type of linear equations have solutions of the for $y=x^r$. Substitution on that function lead to simple polynomial equation. When the polynomial equation has a root of multiplicity larger than 1, then a there $x^r\log x$ gives a another solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x^2y''+xy'-y=0$$
Rewrite the Euler diffirential equation as:
$$y''+\dfrac {xy'-y}{x^2}=0$$
$$y''+\left (\dfrac {y}{x} \right)'=0$$
You have only derivatives in the DE. Integrate.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Cheers :)

Comment: You're welcome @ParasKhosla

Answer (score 2):

Set $y = x^{b}$ and substitute in the equation to find $b$. Indeed
$$
y' = b x^{b-1},\qquad y'' = b(b-1)x^{b-2}
$$
$$
x^2(b(b-1)x^{b-2})+x(b x^{b-1})- x^{b}=0 \\
b(b-1)x^{b}+ b x^{b}- x^{b}=0 \\
(b^2 - 1)x^{b}=0 \implies (b^2 - 1)=0 \iff b \in\{-1,1\}
$$
So the general solution is
$$
y = A x + B x^{-1}
$$
This is based on the observation that the sum of the order of the derivative of $y$ and the degree of $x$ in all terms is the same

Comment: Thanks for answering. This clarifies why the characteristic equation method works. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

rearranging

$x^2y''+2xy'=y+xy'$.

$(x^2y')'=(xy)'$

integrate:

$x^2y'=xy+c$

the rest is easy

Answer (score 1):

One solution of $$y''+\frac{1}{x}y'-\frac{1}{x^2}y=0$$ is $y_1(x)=x$, the other solution is given by
$$y_2(x)=x \int \frac{ e^{-\int x^{-1} dx}}{y_1^2} dx= x \int \frac{dx}{x^3}=-2x^{-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use substitution $t=\ln{x}$ to get $y''_{tt}-y'_t+y'_t-y=0$ or $y''_{tt}-y=0$. Characteristic equation is $\lambda^2-1=0$, from where we get $y(t)=Ae^t+Be^{-t}$ or $y(x)=Ax+\frac{B}{x}$